# custom font not working in pygame, custom font not showing up

Tags: python, fonts, pygame

I tried to use a custom font downloaded on internet but it doesn't work. everything works but the font isn't changing. i installed the font and the path is correct

```
def mainmenutext_function():
    global mainmenutext
    global mainmenutext_width
    global mainmenutext_height
    global ROOTwidth
    global ROOTheight

    mainfont = pygame.font.SysFont("fonts/main_font.ttf", int(ROOTwidth/7))
    mainmenutext = mainfont.render('text', False, (0, 0, 0))
    mainmenutext_width = mainmenutext.get_width()
    mainmenutext_height = mainmenutext.get_height()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution: in `mainfont = pygame.font.SysFont("fonts/main_font.ttf", int(ROOTwidth/7))`

I replaced `pygame.font.SysFont` with `pygame.font.Font`